# Backing up github

Tags: bash, backup, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have a bunch of github directories and have been using a script with the "cp" command to backup to an external USB drive.

I was wondering if I should be backing up directories that I make for upload to github...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really need a backup in addition to your local drive and GitHub - all the files and their history are already stored redundantly.

If your question is instead whether you should create a backup of files created while working **offline** which will later be uploaded to GitHub, then yes. Rather than just copying the files, you could

1. Copy them into the local repository.
2. Commit them.
3. Back up the entire repository.

That way you have a backup which includes all the history, and you can simply overwrite it (using `rsync` rather than `cp` to avoid unnecessary overwrites) when you create new commits. When you come back online you can simply `git push` and it's online.

Comment: I don't understand rsync and how to use it, so I'm stuck with cp.
But thanks for the answer